# Any record of a "扌笨" character anywhere?

Tags: characters, character-identification

So I got this entry in my copy of [成都方言](http://www.amazon.cn/%E6%88%90%E9%83%BD%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80-%E9%A9%AC%E9%AA%A5/dp/B00D3CSCRU/ref=sr_pyc1?ie=UTF8&qid=1442563798&sr=8-1-pinyin&keywords=chengdufangyan)

[image]

> "扌笨" ben ①蘸调料：紧倒～（佐料），不嫌咸了嗦？ ②扳动，扯拉：猴子逮到绳绳儿架势～。

I tried looking for this "扌笨" character:

I did a [zisea.com 两分 search](http://zisea.com/zslf.htm)

[image]

with no results.

I did a [zdic 字典 笔顺](http://www.zdic.net/) search of "12131431412341" (扌 = 121 笨 = 31431412341)

[image]

with no results.

I don't think that this 马骥 is any sort of academic, of any sort, seeing as the dictionary (if you can call it that) doesn't even have any sort of tones markings or notations at all.

Maybe this character was just completely made up by the editors?

Comment: Does it have a Unicode character?

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I usually just use zisea or zdic to find the unicode character....so not really sure.

Comment: I couldn’t find it in the 中华字海, nor in the 汉语大字典. That doesn’t mean anything, though. A possible variant appears in 王力古汉语字典, with the bamboo radical altered: http://postimg.org/image/xhrwwsuij/ This may be a good point to start. Sorry for the bad image quality, though.

Comment: Zisea even records many non-Unicode characters. If you can't find a character there, try 异体字字典, 汉语大字典 and 文字镜. If still no result, then I have to say the character is so rare that would better not be used.

Comment: @Stan Maybe this is a question for another place and time, but: what's the difference between a rare character and a nonexistent character?

Comment: There seems to be a japanese equivalent: http://en.glyphwiki.org/wiki/u2ff0-u624c-u7b28

Comment: @user3306356 if a character can be found in some sources, meanwhile it's seldom used, then it's a rare character. But it's nearly impossible to verify whether a character is literally nonexistent, because looking up all the existing sources is an impossible mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native speaker of sichuanese,  I strongly suspect there is or has been such a character. Obviously this character follows the rule of 形声 and I believe it's coined by the editors or researchers. In my ordinary life, I also pronounce that sound when I express these meanings and speak in Sichuanese, but when it comes to writing, I use other "standard" characters. For example, 拌 for the first and 挣 for the second.

Also, maybe the correct character is 拌 and the standard pronunciation is changed to ben4 in Sichuanese. For example, in Sichuanese, we say dia1, meaning to hold something vertically or to lift something. The pronunciation dia 1 even doesn't exist in standard Chinese. Wikipedia shows the correct character is 提.  I'm not a linguist, but this could happen to ben 4 as well.